# How to use version control in GRPC Protocol Buffer

Tags: protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a `protocol buffer` file in `GRPC` server, and the `SayHello` is defined under `package hello.v1`

```
syntax = "proto3";

package hello.v1;

service GreetService {
    rpc SayHello(SayHelloRequest) returns (SayHelloResponse) {}
}

message SayHelloRequest {
    string name = 1;
}

message SayHelloResponse {
}
```

the function may be changed over time like this:

```
service GreetService {
    rpc SayHello(SayHelloRequest) returns (SayHelloResponse) {}
}

message SayHelloRequest {
    string name = 1;
    uint32 age = 2;
}

message SayHelloResponse {
    string reply_message = 1;
}
```

But for users, they want to have a non-breaking service, so I want to minimize the impact for them. My question is how to keep both the two versions`SayHello`?  Client can call them throw different `namespace` in `cpp` or different `package` in `golang`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should have a single source of truth for your protobuf files. One solution is using a monorepo, i.e. housing both your client and server in the same monorepo. However, this approach is uncommon outside of certain large companies.

Organizations with multiple repos tend to create a separate repo for all of their protobufs which is then included in other repos via submodules or pulled down over the network at buildtime.

Regardless, it is always possible to introduce a breaking change by modifying the proto, even if there is a single source of truth. You might consider running [Buf](https://docs.buf.build/how-to/migrate-from-prototool/) as a presubmit test on all code changes to detect if a breaking change has been introduced.